# Qualified reference and pointers to function

Tags: c++, function, c++11, function-pointers, qualifiers

In C++, it's possible to define qualified function types like:

```
using ftype_01 = int(int) const volatile &&; // OK
```

I am trying to understand the equivalent in terms of pointers:

```
using ftype_02 = int(**)(int); // OK
using ftype_03 = int(*&& const)(int); // Not compiling
using ftype_04 = int(const volatile &&*)(int); // Not compiling
using ftype_05 = int(*const volatile &&)(int); // OK
using ftype_06 = int(*&)(int); // OK
using ftype_07 = int(*&&)(int); // OK
```

And in terms of references:

```
using ftype_08 = int(&)(int); // OK
using ftype_09 = int(&&)(int); // OK
using ftype_10 = int(const &)(int); // Not compiling
using ftype_11 = int(& const)(int); // Not compiling
```

Here are my questions:

- What does the compiling types exactly refer to? (what do they mean)
- How to declare and initialize a variable `f` of these types (so that `decltype(f)` will produce these types)?
- Is `ftype_05` a pointer to a `const volatile &&` function?

Comment: Types are read right to left, inside out. `ftype_05` is a reference to a const volatile pointer to a function.

Comment: To declare a variable, insert a name before the first closing bracket, e.g. `int(*const volatile && myfunc)(int) = ...;`

Comment: The problem is not declaring the variables. It's how to initialize them from a hypothetical function `int myfunction(int x) /* qualifiers */ {return x;}`.

Comment: Your original type `ftype_01` can be qualified because *member functions* can have these qualifiers, and *pointers-to-member-functions* can be decomposed into `ftype_01 C::*` as if they were *pointers-to-members*. The use of these qualified type is quite restricted, see [dcl.fct]p6 -- essentially you can use them directly, pass them as template-arguments, use them to declare member functions (as far as I understand it) and compose *pointer-to-member-function* types.

Comment: How do you initialize a `ftype_01` variable?

Comment: You cannot use this type to declare a variable; this is not one of the allowed usages.

Comment: There's no such thing as an `ftype_01` variable.  Its only valid use is as a function declaration, e.g. `class X { ftype_01 f; };`

Comment: @aschepler Another valid use should be something like `ftype_01 (X::*p) = nullptr;` [on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/48f82fa5d7392bbf)

Comment: *"essentially you can use them directly"* My wording is wrong. You can use them *as types* (pass around etc.), but not to compose other types but pointers-to-members nor create variables.

Comment: There are no qualified functions. Use `int myfunction(int x)`.